# Check if user put in only letters into String

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I wanted to know how do you check if a a user has typed in only letters for his/hers name. If they have not then ask them for their name again.

```
System.out.print("Welcome - What is your family's surname? ");
familySurname = keyboard.nextLine();
while (familySurname.isEmpty())  
{
    System.out.print("Invalid name - What is your family's surname? ");
    familySurname = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (familySurname.matches("[a-zA-Z]"))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far, but it's still accepting numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop condition should be :

```
 while (!familySurname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
     System.out.print("Invalid name - What is your family's surname? ");
     familySurname = keyboard.nextLine();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!familySurname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) // need ! and +
```

Answer (score 1):

Or for speed-

```
public static boolean isAlpha(final String value) {

    if(value == null || value.isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }

    char[] chars = value.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And your snippet can be modified to-

```
while (!isAlpha(familySurname)){

    System.out.print("Invalid name - What is your family's surname? ");
    familySurname = keyboard.nextLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Welcome - What is your family's surname? ");
    familySurname = keyboard.nextLine();
    while (familySurname.isEmpty())  
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid name - What is your family's surname? ");
        familySurname = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (!familySurname.isLetter(source.charAt(i)))
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to capture and trim it?

```
System.out.print("Welcome - What is your family's surname? ");
String familySurname = "";
while (familySurname.length() == 0) { // while we don't have a surname.
  if (keyboard.hasNextLine()) { // check that there is a line of input.
    familySurname = keyboard.nextLine().trim(); // get the line and trim() it.
    for (char c : familySurname.toCharArray()) {
      if (!Character.isLetter(c)) { // Test for not a letter.
        System.out.print("Invalid name - What is your family's surname? ");
        familySurname = "";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```